# Couldn't authenticate third party Api from external credentials

Tags: oauth2, authentication, namedcredentials, auth, xero

I am trying access Xero API from Salesforce. For authentication I created an app in Xero and used id and secret key to create openid auth. provider in Salesforce.
[image]

I used that Authentication provider in named external credential and assigned a permission set in permission set mapping. When I tried to authenticate, it is taking me to Salesforce home page instead of authenticating xero.

[image]

I have provided the images for reference. Can you please help me with the solution?

Thank you